# How to get unique UID for contact in J2ME?

Tags: java-me, contacts, uid, pim, jsr75

How do I get UID for contact which is saved by using PIM in J2ME so that I can use that UID for deleting the contact in future if required?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (contact.countValues(Contact.UID) > 0) {
String UID = contact.getString(Contact.UID, 0));
}
```